# On a single column : Algebraic operation on Aggregate functions

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Is it possible on the same SQL Select Query (no function/procedure nor PL/SQL) to compute an algebraic operation on two aggregate functions ?

```
|  id ||  A  |
|-----||-----|
|  1  || 10  |
|  2  || 20  |
|  3  || 30  |
|  4  || 40  |


SELECT (SELECT SUM(A) FROM Table Where 'id is even') - (SELECT SUM(A) FROM Table Where 'id is odd')
FROM TABLE
WHERE 'condition'
```

Any idea ?

ps : My databse is Oracle 11g

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: @JorgeCampos  Oracle 11g

Comment: Answer it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as this:

```
select sum(case when mod(id,2)=0 then A else 0 end) -
       sum(case when mod(id,2)=0 then 0 else a end)
  from test
 where yourCondition
```

The SQLFiddle is a MySql sample, since the Oracle also have `mod` function it should work as is.

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ba756/2

Comment: sorry I'm using Oracle 11g. Iwas lookin for a more general SQL answer. BTW I used even/odd just as example. The difficulty here is to find my "yourCondition". Any idea on that ?

Comment: @KurtMiller - what do you mean by 'more general'? What is wrong woth this approach? You can replace the mod call with any test you like. Or do you mean you need it to be dynamic, e.g. the 'condition' is a value coming from another table? If so you really need to explain that in your question.

Comment: @KurtMiller I agree here with @AlexPoole you have to explain better your question. Right now this answers it perfectly. The `case` inside the `Sum` function is the condition to odd and even you asked for. And it is also in just one SQL command as you asked.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Ok I get it now. I still get a "missing right parenthesis" is A and a the same thing ?  Or can I add column name in that conditional ?

Comment: If you are getting this error, it means that either you miss a parenthesis for the sum function or the mod function. Take a look.

Comment: @JorgeCampos  HAHAHA You are a GENIUS man !!! Genius!!!. The error was WHERE instead of WHEN. Plus I kept it to "A else 0" in both conditionnal to get the result I wanted....brief Awesome answer here mate. How can I learn about these advanced SQL features ?  Or is there a list somewhere of these advanced stuff someehre u know about ?

Comment: I would recommend a book, any book that teach SQL and advanced SQL techniques. Since almost all follow the SQL ANSI pattern learning one you learn almost all. You can start with this one: ISBN: 0071498508 / 9780071498500 If you read it and do the exercises I'm pretty sure you will learn most of this kind of functions.